# Search for very large prime (greater than $2^{57885161} − 1$) between Crystal Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Denote $p[i]$ as the $i$th prime. In my opinion, the following is true:

**Prime Gap Axiom**
There are always distinct prime factors for $\{p[i],p[i]+1,p[i]+2, \dots , p[i+1]\}$.

**Question 1**
How to give some good algorithm to dispatch distinct prime factors?

**Corollary 1**

$p[i+1]-p[i]\le 1+\pi( p[i+1]/2 ) \le i$, for any integer $i\ge 1$;
There exists at least one prime in the interval  $( n,n+\pi(n)]$.

**Corollary 2**
Define Crystal Number Sequence, `Crystal(2,3)={2^i* 3^j|i>=0,j>=0}`, then  the interval `( Crystal[n],Crystal[n+2])` contains at least one prime, for any $n\ge 1$.

Clearly, Crystal Numbers are very related with Mersenne numbers.

```
indexTop = 30;
Crystal[p1_, p2_] := 
 Sort@Flatten@Table[p1^i*p2^j, {i, 0, indexTop}, {j, 0, indexTop}]
 list = Take[Crystal[2, 3], indexTop]
Graphics[Point[{#, 0}] & /@ list,
 Epilog -> {Orange, Point[Table[{Prime[k], 0}, {k, 1, indexTop}]]}]
```

**Question 2:** 
Can we find (very large) three close numbers c1,c2,c3 which are alike $2^i*3^j$？
exclude composite numbers of the interval (c1, c3) , if there is only one survivor, it must be prime! Is this method feasible? will it be much greater than $2^{57885161} − 1$ ?

---

[Link to Mathematica Notebook](https://github.com/a-boy/a-boy.github.com/blob/master/playmath/Prime%20gap%20inequality.nb)

Comment: For example, {13,14,15,16,17} have distinct prime factors {13,7,3,2,17};
{113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127} have distinct prime factors 
{113,19,  23,  29,  13,  59,  17,  2,    11,   61,  41,  31, 5,    3,    127}

Comment: I tried to improve formatting... can't say it was a complete success. Please review the post.

Comment: The "Crystal Numbers" are tabulated, with much information and links, at https://oeis.org/A003586

Comment: If you take the log of $2^i3^j$, you get $i \log 2 + j \log 3$.  To find close Crystal numbers, you want to find $i,j$ such that $-i \log 2 + j \log 3$ is rather small.  One example is $i=3, j=2$, corresponding to $2^3=8,3^2=9$.  The corresponding $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are $2^{2i},2^i3^j,3^{2j}$.  For my example, this is $64,72,81$ and there are $67,71,73,79$ as primes in the range.  You can use continued fractions to find better approximations to the ratio of the logs.  The prime number theorem will let you estimate the number of primes, but it won't prove there is at least one.

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct prime factors"? $p[i]+2k+1$ will always have $2$ as prime factors for all $k\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I had found an iterative algorithm to dispatch prime factors. Suppose we has the proper primeFactorsList for {1,2,3,...,n-1}, now considering n, n has PrimeNu(n) prime factors, we choose the one that is not dispatched most recently!

```
(*Dispatch Prime Factors for n<128 *)

reversePrimeFactorsList = {3, 2, 1};
n = 3;
i = 2;
PrimeFactors[x_] := FactorInteger[x][[All, 1]];

While[n < 128,
  n++; If[PrimeQ[n], i++; PrependTo [reversePrimeFactorsList, n],

   pos = Max[ 
            FirstPosition[reversePrimeFactorsList, #] & /@ PrimeFactors[n]
            ];
    PrependTo[reversePrimeFactorsList, reversePrimeFactorsList[[pos]]]
   (*choose the one that is not used most recently*)
   ]
  ];
{i, Prime[i], n}
reversePrimeFactorsList
ListPlot[{Range[n], Reverse@reversePrimeFactorsList}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Out34:= {31, 127, 128}

Out35:= {2, 127, 3, 5, 31, 41, 61, 11, 5, 17, 59, 13, 29, 23, 19, 113, 7, 37, \
11, 109, 2, 107, 53, 3, 2, 103, 17, 101, 5, 11, 7, 97, 3, 19, 47, 31, \
23, 13, 2, 89, 11, 29, 43, 17, 7, 83, 41, 3, 5, 79, 2, 11, 19, 5, 37, \
73, 3, 71, 7, 23, 17, 67, 11, 13, 2, 3, 31, 61, 5, 59, 29, 19, 7, 11, \
3, 53, 13, 17, 2, 7, 3, 47, 23, 5, 11, 43, 7, 41, 2, 13, 19, 37, 3, \
5, 17, 11, 2, 31, 2, 29, 7, 3, 13, 5, 2, 23, 11, 7, 5, 19, 3, 17, 2, \
3, 7, 13, 2, 11, 5, 3, 2, 7, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1}